# ngFor with img src, combining two details from the for values

Tags: angular, typescript

My issue is that I have an array with properties

```
export interface IGameTag{
  name: string;
  relativePath: string;
  filename: string;
}
```

I know that I can do this if `relativePath` also contains the `filename`

```
<div *ngFor="let gameTag of gameTags">
   <img [src]="gameTag.relativePath">
</div>
```

But I need to add the `filename` also with the `relativePath`. And these returns compiler in html error

```
<div *ngFor="let gameTag of gameTags">
   <img [src]="gameTag.relativePath + '\\'+ gameTag.filename">
</div>
```

Error is saying

> main.e7b5b0b437c5d1b16f1f.js:185910 Error: Errors during JIT
> compilation of template for GameCardComponent: Parser Error:
> Unexpected token '{' at column 2 in
> [${gameTag.relativePath}\${gameTag.filename}]

as requested `relativePath` sample value

```
relativePath = assets\image
fileName = 123456789.png
```

Comment: Have you tried using the template string? 
Like: <img [src]=`${gameTag.relativePath}\\${gameTag.filename}`>

Comment: @voxtool i have not, will try it

Comment: @voxtool not working, shows `Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: sorry the formatting is messing up my comment. I mean `` and in there you put: ${gameTag.relativePath}\\${gameTag.filename}

Comment: it still says the same @voxtool, regardless if ', `, "

Comment: Can you add the error in your question as well as a demo relative path so we all have a better understanding of what the exact issue is?

Comment: @voxtool added the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```js
<div *ngFor="let gameTag of gameTags">
   <img [src]="`${gameTag.relativePath}\${gameTag.filename}`">
</div>
```

OR

```js
<div *ngFor="let gameTag of gameTags">
   <img src="{{gameTag.relativePath}}\{{gameTag.filename}}">
</div>
```